# Java bit unpacker not matching up with C

Tags: java, c, bit, pack

So I have been given a C program, which I am trying to make more portable by translating to Java, which has been going well. However, I have run into a bit of hangup, which I believe lies in this bit of code. It just a function that unpacks a 30 byte frame. I have a feeling I am running into issues with the variable types, trying to figure out the best way to sub Java types for some that don't carry over from C. If anyone sees where the issue may be, I would appreciate it.

Java:

```
public static byte[] unPackBits(byte[] Src, int bitOffset, byte[] Dst, int bitCount){

    int srcByteOffset, srcBit;
    int dstByteOffset, dstBit;
    char dstMask, srcMask;

    srcByteOffset = bitOffset / 8;
    srcBit = bitOffset % 8;
    srcMask = (char)(0x01<<srcBit);

    dstByteOffset = 0;
    dstBit = 0;
    dstMask = 0x01;

    Dst[dstByteOffset] = '\0';

    for(int b = 0; b < bitCount; b++){
        if((Src[srcByteOffset] & srcMask) != (char)0x00){
            Dst[dstByteOffset] = (byte)(Dst[dstByteOffset]|dstMask);
        }
        else {
            Dst[dstByteOffset] = (byte)(Dst[dstByteOffset] & (~dstMask));
        }

        srcBit++;
        if(srcBit < 8) {
            srcMask = (char)(srcMask<<1);
        }
        else {
            srcByteOffset++;
            srcBit = 0;
            srcMask = 0x01;
        }

        dstBit++;
        if(dstBit < 8) {
            dstMask = (char)(dstMask<<1);
        }
        else {
            dstByteOffset++;
            dstMask = 0x01;
            dstBit = 0;
        }
    }
    return Dst;
}
```

C:

```
void TRB::unPackBits(char *Src, int BitOffset, char *Dst, int BitCount) {
   int srcByteOffset, srcBit;
   int dstByteOffset, dstBit;
   char dstMask, srcMask;

   srcByteOffset   = BitOffset / 8;
   srcBit          = BitOffset % 8;
   srcMask = 0x01<<srcBit;

   dstByteOffset = 0;
   dstBit  = 0;
   dstMask = 0x01;
   Dst[dstByteOffset] = '\0';


   for(int b = 0; b < BitCount; b++) {
      if((Src[srcByteOffset] & srcMask) != (char)0x00) {
         Dst[dstByteOffset] = Dst[dstByteOffset] | dstMask;
      }
      else {
         Dst[dstByteOffset] = Dst[dstByteOffset] & (~dstMask);
      }

      srcBit++;
      if(srcBit < 8) {
         srcMask = srcMask<<1;
      }
      else {
         srcByteOffset++;
         srcBit = 0;
         srcMask = 0x01;
      }

      dstBit++;
      if(dstBit < 8) {
         dstMask = dstMask<<1;
      }
      else {
         dstByteOffset++;
         dstMask = 0x01;
         dstBit = 0;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: What output do you get for each version?  Have you tried printing intermediate variables and comparing?

Comment: I am sure I am choosing poor prints, but all that wins me is loads of undecipherable data that I can't begin to tell if there are any major differences in it.

Comment: A short explanation what this.. thing is actually trying to do would be quite useful - not many people will have the patience to go through the execution in detail and make sure they understand the semantics correctly

Comment: Of course. It takes in a byte[], an int with the bit offset, another byte[] (typecast most of the time) and a second int saying how many bits that piece of information is. It then returns the unpacked (shifted or inverted) bits in the second byte[], with whatever length was held in the second int.

Comment: your C++ char is probably 8 bits, while your Java char's are 16 bit.

Comment: Two things: that looks like C++ (it uses the scope resolution operator `::` ), also Java more portable than C?

Comment: @Cat, check what nos says, char in C is 8bit unsigned, java char is 16 unsigned, and byte is 8bits BUT signed.

Comment: @Cat: You're not looking for *major* differences.  You're looking for *any* differences.  The first print output which differs tells you the first point in your code where the behaviour diverges.  That will help you locate the bug.  Ideally, you'll be able to to identify a single erroneous line of code.

Comment: @ninjalj, yes you're right, it is technically C++, but whoever wrote it used mainly C syntax.

Comment: @bestss, do you think it's possible to sub the java byte for the C char then? Or would the sign mess it up?

Comment: @Cat, sure you can but any time you convert from byte to int you'd need something like `(int) b & 0xFF` and when you covert from int to byte `(byte)(i >>> 8) & 0xFF)`  [to get the 2nd byte in the example]. Alternatively (easier and better) use `ByteBuffer.wrap(Src)` and just use the necessary methods. You may need to switch the byteOrder to little endian (default is big)

Comment: @bestsss, Thank you! The bytebuffer.wrap does exactly what I was basically trying to write on my own, I had no idea about it. Works great!

Comment: @Cat, formulate a proper answer, post it yourself, and accept it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that C doesn't have a built in way to easily access data inside a char *. The unPackBits function is just extracting data from a certain location (BitOffset) with a certain length (BitCount) and returning it in the same form. Then that data has to be cast to the appropriate types, be it bool, int, double, etc.

Java, on the other hand has a built in way to handle the same issue. Data that is stored in a byte array can be accessed by using ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[]). ByteBuffer has functions that return int, double, long, short, float, and char, as well as ones to put all of those types and a few other useful functions, like translating the entire structure into an int array. Each of these only need to be told the offset, they hold in memory the BitCount. The only primitive data type it doesn't handle is boolean, so I will still be unpacking with the byte array, not a problem since I know exactly where in the array those values are held.

As for the bit shifting, shift the entire array before wrapping it as a ByteBuffer, as suggested by @vidstige, in the same way the first if else in the for loop does, and everything will be in order.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have stumbled upon a very common problem with [endianness](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/endian.html). C and java *might* have diffrent ways of representing an `int` depending on the architecture of the machine running the c-code.

Typically c-programs should convert multi-byte integers into [network byte order](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Byte-Order.html) to simplify portability work like the one your doing right now.

To get the byte-ordering correct you'll have to shift your bits around using the [bit-shift](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and  "and" operators.

Also of interest - the [nio package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) has functionality for easily handle LSB byte-order integers typically produced by legacy c-code.

Comment: weird? the are only 2 types, little and big endian, w/ java being big and x86 is little endian.

Comment: actually there is a lot of other exotic combination found out there in the wild, see for example this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian

Comment: @vidstige, sure you can encode (shuffle) the bytes as you see fit, the point is that java supports only 2: little/big via `ByteBuffer.order()`

Comment: @bestsss see what you mean. That was a bad phrasing, I've clearified what the nio package provides now.

Comment: I thought that could be part of it. I will check it out and see if that helps.

Comment: But I know the data in in network byte order. Since I am using Java to capture it anyway, I wouldn't think it would be a problem. I think I will just go in and test the variable representation for both and see if I can find any differences.